# Modify on multiple jointed table sql mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, join

I have made this joins on 5 tables and it looks like this :

```
   SELECT Marque.nom AS "Brand"
        , Modele.nom AS "Model"
        , Annee.nom "Year"
        , Motorisation.nom AS "Motor"
        , Fichier.prix_1 AS "Normal price"
        , Fichier.prix_2 AS "Discounted price"
   FROM   Marque
          JOIN Modele ON Modele.idMarque = Marque.id
          JOIN Annee ON Annee.idModele = Modele.id
          JOIN Motorisation ON Motorisation.idAnnee = Annee.id
          JOIN Fichier ON Fichier.idMotorisation = Motorisation.id;
```

So it returns this :

[image]

And I need to edit Normal price and Discounted price exported in csv ... or directly on MySql but I can't because I have no unique colum " Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

Can anyone help me on how to do this?

Best regards.

Fichier look like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a 100 % sure about this but i think if you do an group by on one of the fichier values you can edit the prices.

```
SELECT Marque.nom AS "Brand", 
       Modele.nom AS "Model", 
       Annee.nom "Year", 
       Motorisation.nom AS "Motor",
       Fichier.prix_1 AS "Normal price", 
       Fichier.prix_2 AS "Discounted price"
FROM   Marque
JOIN Modele ON Modele.idMarque = Marque.id
JOIN Annee ON Annee.idModele = Modele.id
JOIN Motorisation ON Motorisation.idAnnee = Annee.id
JOIN Fichier ON Fichier.idMotorisation = Motorisation.id
GROUP BY Fichier.idMotorisation
```

You will only be able to edit fichier i think, and if not than you'd have to do it in excel i'm afraid

Okay i have a workaround to help you i think:

First you execute this query

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',Fichier.idMotorisation) AS ID_ARRAY
FROM   Marque
JOIN Modele ON Modele.idMarque = Marque.id
JOIN Annee ON Annee.idModele = Modele.id
JOIN Motorisation ON Motorisation.idAnnee = Annee.id
JOIN Fichier ON Fichier.idMotorisation = Motorisation.id
GROUP BY Fichier.idMotorisation
```

This will provide you with a long string as a result of all id's concatenated by a comma. you will then insert this string into the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Fichier
WHERE Fichier.idMotorisation IN (*Insert string here, not as string just as comma seperated values between the brackets*)
```

that should give you a result you can work on.

EDIT:

This is the best you can get in one editable query:

```
SELECT Fichier.*
FROM   Marque
JOIN Modele ON Modele.idMarque = Marque.id
JOIN Annee ON Annee.idModele = Modele.id
JOIN Motorisation ON Motorisation.idAnnee = Annee.id
JOIN Fichier ON Fichier.idMotorisation = Motorisation.id
GROUP BY Fichier.idMotorisation
```

if you now add other info to your select it will say you can't edit because of a join (not because of lack of key, which was our first problem)

Comment: I really want to edit it like this, I can do it in "fichier" but I have to look id each time I modify it will takes a while. I can't edit even if I use GROUP BY

Comment: @Hayk can you try the workaround i just gave you, i think that would work

Comment: if I do like this I will work on fichier and won't have any information from the other tables. If for example I have an AUDI A3 2009 2.0 TDI.  audi will be in MARQUE, A3 will be in MODELE , 2009 will be in ANNEE , 2.0 TDI will be in motorisation.   And then I can create anything in fichier for AUDI A3 2009 2.0 TDI, fichier is the frenche for file. So I can't have anything in fichier and nothing in annee, modele ....

Comment: i don't understand exactly what you are trying to do, you can't set a different price for different (files?) by joining them to the same row. that is exactly why you got the first error, you should probably just make a csv if it's just for an export for a client or something. make a csv open in excel and you can edit it easily

Comment: it's not for a client, it is for a website. I don't need to modify it offline. I updated first with a screenshot of ficher

Comment: so you want to edit the prices based on the models? but you realise that one price being used by 2 models can't all of a sudden be split into 2 prices without manually doing so, or do you just want some car information to be able to better determine the price?

Comment: Yeah I just want to see the model name for which I change the price

Comment: if you add a sqlfiddle it might be even easier to try stuff: http://sqlfiddle.com/ i'm going to bed in a bit though, if you set up sql fiddle i can take a quick look now or in the morning

Comment: Okay you can edit if you join stuff, but only if you select a key value and other values from one table, you can't select values from other tables.

Comment: @Hayk edited my answer, you can only get to show all the values in fichier, if that's not enough you'll have to make your own view for it if you have to do it more often. Make a table using select and than make javascript functions with ajax to call an update to edit the price for a certain id. but that is quite a lot of work ;)

Comment: thanks, I will edit looking each id meaning. Lot of work for one time use.